# String stops appending after char 00H

Tags: c#, string, char, hex

I am doing some experiments and as part of the exploratory process I am trying to write a program that would present files in a similar fashion a hex editor would do.

I load a file using `FileStream` and I write all the bytes to a byte array. I then loop through the array and write the bytes out in a hex format in blocks with a width of my choosing (16 bytes in the case of this example).

Next to each line I want to write the bytes in ASCII format but when I encounter `00H` all the text after that is not appended to the string.

The code looping through the bytes is as follows:

```
while (j < data.Length - 1)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= blockWidth - 1; i++)
    {
        if (j < data.Length - 1)
        {
            byteBlock[i] = data[j];
            charBlock[i] = Convert.ToChar(data[j]); //ASCII Characters to be appended                       
            j += 1;
        }
    }
    sTemp = new string(charBlock);
    hex += BitConverter.ToString(byteBlock) + "      " + sTemp;//bug-causing line
    hex += Environment.NewLine;
}
textBox1.Text = hex;
```

The text in `textBox1` is only the following line:

```
D0-CF-11-E0-A1-B1-1A-E1-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00        ÐÏà¡±á
```

There are 16 bytes of hex data and only 8 ASCII characters (2 of them don't show on this page).

I added some breakpoints and stepped through the code, the loop runs to the end with no problems.

When I comment out the part where I add `sTemp` to `hex` like this:

```
sTemp = new string(charBlock);//Output confirms the bug is not in this line
hex += BitConverter.ToString(byteBlock);// +"      " + sTemp;//bug-causing line
hex += Environment.NewLine;
```

I get the following output:

```
D0-CF-11-E0-A1-B1-1A-E1-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-3E-00-03-00-FE-FF-09-00
06-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-01-00-00-00
01-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-10-00-00-02-00-00-00
03-00-00-00-FE-FF-FF-FF-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF...
```

Could someone please explain to my why this is happening and also what I should do in order to fix it?

Comment: Ideally, `00H` should not be printed using `string`. You can think of replacement like print it as `\0` or as in `NotePad++` printed as `NUL`. Also, there are more than just `00H` which cannot be printed in `ASCII`/`UTF-8`. You may need to create a whole dictionary needed for that. ASCII has at least [33 chars non-printable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Next to each line I want to write the bytes in ASCII format but when I encounter 00H all the text after that is not appended to the string.

Yes it is - it's just not shown in the text box. (You're also using ISO-8859-1, not ASCII. ASCII doesn't contain any accented characters etc.)

Most Windows Forms controls are very thin wrappers over Win32 controls, and those treat U+0000 as the end of a string.

In your second piece of code, you convert the bytes into text using hex, and then you can see that the data *is* there.

Basically, you shouldn't try to display non-text as if it's text. If you really, really want to do that, I'd just use

```
text = text.Replace('\u0000', ' ');
```

to avoid the Win32 control from "seeing" a Unicode NUL character and stopping.

Comment: Thanks, this works. I don't have the pressing need to display non-text characters, I just needed a way to display a place holder for these bytes, which you showed me just now. Most of this data is in anyway not intended to be displayed as text, it's just for me to make better sense of what's going on.